# Given array, write a function that returns an order object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to write a function, allCandyOrders(inventory), that returns an order object (I'm not sure what that means). The keys should be the names of the candies, and the values should be the amounts to be ordered. If the stock is greater than weekly average, order 0
if the stock is less than weekly average, order 2 times the average.

Example output:

```
{
  "Twizzlers": 400,
  "Sour Patch Kids": 200,
  "Milk Duds": 0,
  "Now and Laters": 0
}
```

Given array:

```
let inventory = [
  { candy: "Twizzlers", inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 },
  { candy: "Sour Patch Kids", inStock: 90, weeklyAverage: 100 },
  { candy: "Milk Duds", inStock: 300, weeklyAverage: 170 },
  { candy: "Now and Laters", inStock: 150, weeklyAverage: 40 }
];
```

What I have so far:

```
function allCandyOrders(inventory) {
  for (let i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
    if (inventory[i].inStock < inventory[i].weeklyAverage) {
      return inventory[i].weeklyAverage * 2;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a new object that will store the result you want and put values there inside `allCandyOrders` function.

```js
let inventory = [
  { candy: "Twizzlers", inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 },
  { candy: "Sour Patch Kids", inStock: 90, weeklyAverage: 100 },
  { candy: "Milk Duds", inStock: 300, weeklyAverage: 170 },
  { candy: "Now and Laters", inStock: 150, weeklyAverage: 40 }
];

function allCandyOrders(inventory) {
  const result = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < inventory.length; i ++) {
    if (inventory[i].inStock < inventory[i].weeklyAverage) {
      result[inventory[i].candy] = inventory[i].weeklyAverage * 2;
    } else {
      result[inventory[i].candy] = 0;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(allCandyOrders(inventory));
```

Simply, you can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let inventory = [
  { candy: "Twizzlers", inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 },
  { candy: "Sour Patch Kids", inStock: 90, weeklyAverage: 100 },
  { candy: "Milk Duds", inStock: 300, weeklyAverage: 170 },
  { candy: "Now and Laters", inStock: 150, weeklyAverage: 40 }
];

function allCandyOrders(inventory) {
  return inventory.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (cur.inStock < cur.weeklyAverage) {
      acc[cur.candy] = cur.weeklyAverage * 2;
    } else {
      acc[cur.candy] = 0;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

console.log(allCandyOrders(inventory));
```

Comment: Thanks again Derek, you've been a huge help. In the first solution you created a new object with const result = {}, then when you log the results you used result[inventory[i].candy] = inventory[i].weeklyAverage * 2; what exactly is the result [ ] doing?

Comment: To assign a value to specific key on Object, you can use `result[key] = value`.

Answer (score 1):

When you have an array for which each array item needs to be transformed into a key-value pair in an object somehow, the most elegant method to use is `Object.fromEntries`. That lets you use `return` like you're trying to do, except you need to return an *entry* (key-value pair) rather than just a value:

```js
const inventory = [
  { candy: "Twizzlers", inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 },
  { candy: "Sour Patch Kids", inStock: 90, weeklyAverage: 100 },
  { candy: "Milk Duds", inStock: 300, weeklyAverage: 170 },
  { candy: "Now and Laters", inStock: 150, weeklyAverage: 40 }
];
const order = Object.fromEntries(
  inventory.map(({ candy, inStock, weeklyAverage }) => [
    candy,
    inStock > weeklyAverage ? 0 : weeklyAverage * 2
  ])
);
console.log(order);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is definitely an efficient solution..I'll get there one day!

Answer (score 1):

Array reduce is correct

```js
let inventory = 
  [ { candy: 'Twizzlers',       inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 } 
  , { candy: 'Sour Patch Kids', inStock:  90, weeklyAverage: 100 } 
  , { candy: 'Milk Duds',       inStock: 300, weeklyAverage: 170 } 
  , { candy: 'Now and Laters',  inStock: 150, weeklyAverage:  40 } 
  ] 

const allCandyOrders = arr => arr.reduce((r,c)=>
  {
  r[c.candy] = c.inStock < c.weeklyAverage ? c.weeklyAverage *2 : 0
  return r
  },{})
 
console.log ( allCandyOrders(inventory) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```